# Generating Postgresql table using java Annotations

Tags: java, postgresql, nullpointerexception, dynamically-generated

I'm looking into annotations and how hibernate works, to get a better understanding of it.

I know my code might not be the best quality, and I will be fixing it up when I can resolve my exception, I keep getting a `NullPointerException`, but I cannot see why, what did I do wrong?

The main in this class is only there to find the cause of the problem, I have another class that will use this one, from my other class I am able to add data to my table, but I need to be able to generate a table using annotations, and this is where I my get my `NullPointerException` I cannot generate my table

This is my `StackTrace`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at psybergate.grad2018.javafnds.javabasics.annotations.hw3.vendor.DatabaseManager.generateDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:84)
at psybergate.grad2018.javafnds.javabasics.annotations.hw3.vendor.DatabaseManager.main(DatabaseManager.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at psybergate.grad2018.javafnds.javabasics.annotations.hw3.vendor.DatabaseManager.generateDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:82)
... 1 more
```

This is my code

```
package psybergate.grad2018.javafnds.javabasics.annotations.hw3.vendor;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import psybergate.grad2018.javafnds.javabasics.annotations.hw3.annotations.DomainClass;
import psybergate.grad2018.javafnds.javabasics.annotations.hw3.annotations.DomainProperty;
import psybergate.grad2018.javafnds.javabasics.annotations.hw3.developer.Customer;

/**
* @since 26 Apr 2018
* @author christiaan.dotze
*/
public class DatabaseManager {

private String addField = "";

private Connection connect = null;

private Statement statement = null;

private String primaryKey = "";

private String tableName = "";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DatabaseManager manager = new DatabaseManager();
    try {
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        cust.setCustomerNum("11");
        cust.setFirstName("John");
        cust.setLastName("Doe");
        cust.setAge(27);
        cust.setDateOfBirth(1991);

        manager.generateDatabase(cust);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | SQLException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("An error occured", ex);
    }
}

public String getTableName(Object obj) {
    Annotation[] domainClassAnnotation = obj.getClass().getDeclaredAnnotations();
    for (Annotation annotation : domainClassAnnotation) {
        if (annotation instanceof DomainClass) {
            tableName = ((DomainClass) annotation).name();
        }
    }
    return tableName;
}

private String getDatabaseFields(Object obj) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
    Field[] decladedFields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : decladedFields) {
        Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
        for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
            if (annotation instanceof DomainProperty) {
                DomainProperty myAnnotation = (DomainProperty) annotation;
                if (myAnnotation.primaryKey() == true) primaryKey = myAnnotation.name();
                if (myAnnotation.unique() == false) {
                    addField += myAnnotation.name() + " " + myAnnotation.dataType() + ",\n";
                } else {
                    addField += myAnnotation.name() + " " + myAnnotation.dataType() + " " + "NOT NULL" + ",\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    addField += "PRIMARY KEY(" + primaryKey + ")\n";
    return addField;
}

public void generateDatabase(Object obj)
        throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
    createConnection();
    getTableName(obj);
    getDatabaseFields(obj);
    try {
        statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE " + getTableName(obj) + "(\n" + getDatabaseFields(obj) + ")");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

private void createConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/", "postgres", "1234");
}

public int add(Object obj, String data)
        throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    createConnection();
    statement = connect.createStatement();
    return statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO " + getTableName(obj) + " VALUES (" + data + ")");
}
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful, if you point out where the corresponding line numbers are (DatabaseManager.java:84, etc)

Comment: Have you tried to debug the issue? Just go step-by step with debugger in IDE you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have null object 'statement' in the 'generateDatabase' method. The 'statement' field is initialized at the 'add' method when 'add' is never runs.

Try to put

```
statement = connect.createStatement();
```

after

```
createConnection();
```

in 'generateDatabase' method.

Comment: I cant believe I missed this, It's solved now thank you